# System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load assembly System.Drawing

Tags: android-webview, xamarin.forms

I meet this error in a Xamarin.forms project using WebView and local html base url:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? Nom de fichier :
>   'System.Drawing.dll'    à
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    à
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    à
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() Almicantarat.Droid

I read that:
[System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly System.Web in Mono for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228830/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-assembly-system-web-in-mono-for)
but I don't know which client's source code I should compile.

I read that:
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150510/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-drawing-version-4-0-0-0)
but in my project, there is no reference to System.Drawing !!

See my references:
[my android project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqUA7.png)

Comment: Finally, I found the system.drawing reference in mono.android. What is going wrong ? Should I compile mono.android myself ? where could I find it ? does Xamarin provide it ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

-> Close the solution

-> Delete all contents of the Packages folder (all the DLL's referenced through Nuget)

-> Restart the solution

-> Build (this will cause Nuget to get all DLL's again based on the packages.config)